# putty error message ..putty saying remote side unexpectedly closed network connection as shown below what should i do

Tags: putty

putty is giving me putty host unexpectedly closed  what should I [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgFuS.png) do please

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening after it's been sitting at the login prompt for a while, the connection is timing out. Log in faster.

If it's happening quickly, before you can start typing, you most likely have network problems between you and your host. Talk to your IT people.

Comment: When I trying to login the setting will appear and I will put IP and click open it will just staying darck and after some thing it will say side unexpectedly closed connection

Comment: The image you have posted, it was clearly sitting at a login prompt before it disconnected. You need to type in your user ID.